# Checkbox to enable/disable other items when checked

Tags: sql, oracle, checkbox, oracle-apex

I have this report, every column is generated by the APEX_ITEM package.

```
APEX_ITEM.CHECKBOX2, APEX_ITEM.DATE_POPUP2
```

[image]

When the checkbox is checked, I would like to enable the DATE_POPUP2 of that row. And disabled it when the checkbox is unchecked.

Is there any way to do this?

Report query:

```
SELECT APEX_ITEM.CHECKBOX2(1,a.USR_CODIGO,DECODE(NVL((SELECT 1 
                                             FROM   PROYECTOS_ROLES_USUARIOS pru
                                             WHERE  pru.USR_CODIGO = a.USR_CODIGO  
                                             AND    pru.PRY_ID = :P92_PRY_ID),0),0,'UNCHECKED',1,'CHECKED')) as Incluir,
 a.USR_CODIGO as Usuario, APEX_ITEM.SELECT_LIST_FROM_QUERY(2, NVL((SELECT pru.ROL_CODIGO 
                                             FROM   PROYECTOS_ROLES_USUARIOS pru
                                             WHERE  pru.USR_CODIGO = a.USR_CODIGO  
                                             AND    pru.PRY_ID = :P92_PRY_ID),null), 'SELECT r.ROL_DESCRIPCION, r.ROL_CODIGO 
 FROM ROLES r WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ROLES_USUARIOS ru
       WHERE ru.ROL_CODIGO = r.ROL_CODIGO
       AND ru.USR_CODIGO = ''' || a.USR_CODIGO || ''') and r.ROL_CODIGO not in(''MNI_RRHH'',''CAJ_COMPRAS'',''CAJ_VENTAS'',''CTA_CTE_CLIENTES''
       ,''CTA_CTE_PROVEEDORES'',''TCM_ALQUILERES'',''TCM_COMPRAS'') order by 1', null, 'YES', '%NULL%', '--') as Rol, 
       NVL((SELECT APEX_ITEM.DATE_POPUP2(3, prus.PRU_FECHA_INICIO, 'dd/mm/yyyy')
                from PROYECTOS_ROLES_USUARIOS prus where prus.PRY_ID = :P92_PRY_ID and prus.USR_CODIGO = a.USR_CODIGO),
                    APEX_ITEM.DATE_POPUP2(3, TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'dd/mm/yyyy'), 'dd/mm/yyyy')) as Fecha_Inicio FROM USUARIOS a  WHERE a.USR_FECHA_BAJA IS NULL AND exists (SELECT 1
                FROM  WWV_FLOW_FND_USER
                WHERE USER_NAME = a.USR_CODIGO) order by 1;
```

Comment: Are you setting up some distinct id for the DATE_POPUP2 on each row?

Comment: 1) Provide the query used 2) how proficient are you with javascript? Will you be able to maintain it after you've copied provided code? 3) better yet, a workspace on apex.oracle.com would be great.

Comment: 1) Query added. 2) I am not that good with Javascript but i want to learn, thats why i am asking.

Answer (score 0):

As Tom suggests in his comment, there are various ways to do this using JavaScript. You could just apply CSS classes to your checkbox and date item and then use some jQuery to perform the action.

Defining this event binding in your page preferences in the 'Execute when page loads' section would do it.

```
  $('input.myCheckBox').click(function() {
     var enabled = $(this).prop('checked');
     var myDate  = $(this).closest('tr').find('input.myDate');
     myDate.prop('disabled', !enabled);      
     if(enabled) {
        myDate.next('img').show();
     } else {
        myDate.next('img').hide();
     }         
  });
```

With this approach you do not need to apply IDs to your elements. You could also go down the dynamic action route, perhaps triggering a custom event which is interpreted by the dynamic action?